# how to insert text in specific empty lines of a file (bash)

Tags: bash, awk

this is an example of my file:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

[section 1]
DDDD
EEEE

[section 2]
FFFF
GGGG

[section 3]
IIII
```

I need to insert A) the line `XXXX` as the last line of section 1, and B) the line `YYYY` in the line just after section 3 (but creating an entirely new line so both sections 2 and 3 are always separated by an empty line). This would be the expected result:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

[section 1]
DDDD
EEEE
XXXX

[section 2]
FFFF
GGGG

YYYY
[section 3]
IIII
```

It could be done in a bash file using sed?

Comment: Are you looking to change a record that starts with the text `[section 1]` regardless of the order it appears in the input file or contains the text `[section 1]` in any line or are you trying to change the second record in the input file regardless of its content? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements as right now it's very unclear/ambiguous.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question is "Yes, there is a way". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We (most of us anyway) are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier using `awk` than `sed`. Using `awk` you can do this with an empty `RS`:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= '/\[section 1]/{$0 = $0 "\nXXXX"}
 /\[section 3]/{$0 = "YYYY\n" $0} 1' file
```

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

[section 1]
DDDD
EEEE
XXXX

[section 2]
FFFF
GGGG

YYYY
[section 3]
IIII
```

[Working Demo](https://ideone.com/c4m196)

Comment: Hi, I tried that line, but obtained this result:YYYY
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

[section 1]
DDDD
EEEE

[section 2]
FFFF
GGGG

[section 3]
IIII
XXXX what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Ed, it is edited now. @AndrésF: Can you check your input file using `cat -A file` to make sure there is no DOS line ending.

Comment: Also make sure your input data is same as what shown in question. Check this working demo: https://ideone.com/c4m196